# Is it possible to integrate Hudson with an Assembla space?

Tags: hudson, assembla

I'm looking at Assembla and considering signing up for a monthly subscription. I am currently developing web applications in Java and I've set up builds in Hudson for all of my projects and libraries.

Is it possible to set up communication between Assembla and Hudson in some way, so that the build statuses are shown in an Assembla space? I don't need any Assembla->Hudson triggers as my Hudson instance will poll the repository itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found an answer somewhere? I can't find a way to make Hudson access my private SVN repository on Assembla - I guess because of this issue: http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-6392

Comment: I would like to know if there is any updates about that?

Regards

Comment: You should be able to connect to svn via the subversion plugin including adding authentication.  If you need to connect to multiple assembla svn repositories with different credentials use svn.assembla.com and subversion.assembla.com - at least that gets you two creds, but multiple repos with same creds will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I started to investigate myself and it works pretty well and almost seamlessly.
Have a look at this discussion there : http://forum.assembla.com/forums/1-Tools/topics/2860-Assembla-+-git-+-Hudson